# Using TikZDevice and APA 7 class: Including a figure note for a plot (including the plot by include())

Tags: include, tikzdevice, apa7

I am using TikZDevice for including a R-Plot in Latex, using the APA7-Documentclass. The documentary of the APA7-Class lists \figurenote{} as "Formats figure note when placed after \includegraphic, \fitfigure, or similar command within \begin{figure} and \end{figure}." However, it doesn`t seem to work, is there another way for including a figure note?
Following a short example of my code for reproducing my issue:

```
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{tikz}
\author{}
\title{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}
\abstract{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some Caption} 
\centering
%Here I am using \input{plot.tex} for my plot but following I include a TikZ circle
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}       
\figurenote{Test} %This here does not work
\label{plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by updating to the newest version of APA7.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/194080)

Comment: @Mensch Since the question has no comments and this is its first answer, I think this _is_ an answer to solve the question.